# Java and XML output

Tags: java, xml

I have a question about output in XML. I have scanner  for  1st and 2nd number... And i would like to prepare xml output file with form (e.g  1st number is 10,  2nd is 15)

```
<line>
    <Point>
        <X>10</X>
    </Point>
</line>
<line>
    <Point>
         <X>11</X>
    </Point>
</line>

<line>
    <Point>
       <X>12</X>
    </Point>
</line>
```

and so on ... till second number

```
try{


               XMLOutputFactory f = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
               XMLStreamWriter w = f.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output));

               w.writeComment("XMLOutput");


               w.writeStartElement("line");
               w.writeStartElement("Point");
               w.writeStartElement("X");
              String pointX0 = String.valueOf(a);
               w.writeCharacters(pointX0);
              w.writeEndElement();



              w.writeEndElement();

               }
               w.writeEndElement();
               w.writeEndDocument();
               w.close();
                } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Output.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
    }
```

Iam Struggling with for loop but I dont know where shall i put it ...

Comment: Improving your grammar and the description of your problem will help you get answers faster.

Comment: sorry m8s ... I Have  two numbers (user´s input) and i Would like to create output as u can see  above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XStream http://x-stream.github.io/ to serialize the XML you need from POJOs.

Comment: @DRastislav - Also consider a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.  One is included in the JDK/JRE:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html